# Which Python should I install (and how) when using msys2?

Tags: python, mingw, msys2

While the current official Python version is 3.6, msys2 provides *two* packages for `python3`:

- `msys/python3`, [currently using 3.4](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/blob/7d77534a4f03a28ff36649db124e51cf4eb4414a/python3/PKGBUILD#L7)
- `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python3`, [currently using 3.5](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MINGW-packages/blob/9f5f700254f3038c47a79c83986fb1edc4f7abcc/mingw-w64-python3/PKGBUILD#L19)

So which version should I use when and how? Can't I just use the Windows 3.6 and somehow tell `pacman` to use that? Or can I get 3.6 running in a msys/mingw'd version and also use that in Windows so I don't need two/three installations?

Comment: No, the major (3) and minor (6) versions must be the same because they link with the python source code.  Your options are to use an earlier version of python, wait for a new version of the module, or compile it yourself.

Comment: `msys/python3` behaves like Python on Linux (with some patches) and `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python3` is similar to Python for Windows.
It is a little outdated because of amount patches that need to be updated/reworked.

Using Python for Windows without MSYS2 specific patches may lead to non-oblivious errors.

Comment: @mati865 I read some more - shouldn't the only difference between msys/python and mingw/native python be the support of cygwin-style paths? Or what does the mingw-version provide in addition to the native version? The only thing I'd have hoped for would have been better compiling support, but e.g. `pip install numpy` also fails, though due to a lack of `python35.dll`. I'll have to dig deeper...

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler Did you figure it out?  Is `msys/python3` more easy to use in compiling package? Do not require msvc++. ?

Comment: @Mithril Unfortunately no progress nor time to test... If you find something, please add an answer. Otherwise you try a bounty...

Answer (score 7):

This is what I'm using on msys2 to install python3:

```
$ pacman -Syuu
```

Close and restart msys2.

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-bsddb3 mingw-w64-x86_64-gexiv2 mingw-w64-x86_64-ghostscript mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-cairo mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-gobject mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-icu mingw-w64-x86_64-iso-codes mingw-w64-x86_64-hunspell mingw-w64-x86_64-hunspell-en mingw-w64-x86_64-enchant
```

To deal with this error "No intltool or version < 0.25.0, build_intl is aborting" perform the following:

```
$ pacman -S intltool
```

Add these to test:

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-lxml
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-jsonschema
```

Execute this command to verify python3 is properly installed:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.4
```

For details please see https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gramps_for_Windows_with_MSYS2

Comment: I already got Python3 installed (and meanwhile it's been updated to 3.6.5 (mingw64) and 3.6.2 (msys2) respectively) so I'm afraid you misunderstood my question - I wanted to know which of these three Pythons I currently have (native windows, mingw64, msys2) I should use when and why, and whether I can at least get rid of one of them due to redundancy.

Comment: Nice link to gramps by the way, sounds worth checking out independently

Comment: OK, I don't know much about the msys/python3, but it looks like the mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 has been successful with the gramps project.

Comment: Is it safe to link /usr/bin to /mingw64/bin for msys2? After an updatedb I found where Python3 had been installed

Answer (score 7):

It can be confusing why there are two versions of Python, but both serve different use cases:

1. MINGW - Windows native applications
2. MSYS2 - POSIX applications emulated to work in Windows

MINGW refers to executables that are compiled using the MINGW GCC Compiler and target the Win32 API. MSYS2 refers to executables that are compiled by MSYS2 GCC Compiler and make use of a POSIX emulation layer.

I understand as a user this can be confusing, why do you care which compiler and API Python is compiled against? Well some programs you may want to make use of, are dependent on running in a POSIX environment. It would be very hard and time consuming to port these applications to Windows. In these cases, MSYS2 provides an emulation layer to allow these applications to work. Unfortunately, making use of this emulation layer is very very slow.

So in general, if you can use the MINGW version of Python, you should because it will be much faster. But if you are trying to run a Python application that depends on being in a POSIX environment, then MSYS2 provides an emulation layer to help make it work.

For more information, the [Git for Windows Wiki](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/The-difference-between-MINGW-and-MSYS2) provides a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably kind of late, but I use the native Windows install of python in MSYS2. The way I did this was to ensure that Python added the environment variable. After this, I created a new Windows environment variable `PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Glen.Nicholls\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages`. I also set MSYS to inherit in the `MINGW64.ini`. Now, I add the alias for `pip` and `python` to my .bashrc:

```
alias python='$PYTHONPATH/../../python.exe'
alias pip='$PYTHONPATH/../../Scripts/pip.exe'
```

This isn't the cleanest solution, but it works in my environment just fine. Also, keep in mind that if you run `which python` it will not point to the correct install.

Another method without creating aliases and all the above would be to change your PATH to include the inherited Windows PATH before the msys PATH. You can either edit this manually or put something fancy in your .bash_profile or .bashrc.