# install pygtk for python 3.6.1 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pygtk

Since `PIL.ImageGrab()` gave me some problems, I read further into the topic and it seems that `gtk` is the better solution for making Screenshots.
But I don't understand which packages are actually working and which are deprecated.
trying

```
pip install pygtk
```

gives me

```
ERROR: Could not import dsextras module: Make sure you have installed pygobject.
```

`pygobject` doesn't exist, installing `gobject` doesn't help.

I tried some variants of the module name like `python3-` or just `3` at the end, but I don't seem to get the right one.

Answer (score 2):

The full chat session about this is [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40442255#40442255). The original solution can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932407/which-python-should-i-install-and-how-when-using-msys2), especially the comment made by @cdarke.

So anyway, the solution is to use Python3.5 intead of 3.6 or newer, at least until MSYS2 is updated.

As a sidenote, you really don't want to use pygtk (which is based on Gtk2). Use pygobject like such:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

Answer (score 0):

for GTK+, you have to do the following:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

and not:

```
import gtk
```