# ModuleNotFoundError: No module nomed 'gi'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, gtk3

Using instructions from this website https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php
I executed the following two lines from a Windows 10 MSYS2 window:
   pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
   pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-gobject

No errors were reported so I assume everything went according to plan.

However the first line of the following script
   import gi
   gi.require_version ('Gtk', '3.0')
   from gi.repository import Gtk

Resulted in:
... line 16 in 
   import 'gi'
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

How do I get GTK3+ installed on Windows 10 so my scripts can utilize it along with PyInstaller?

I have found and used several advisories on the internet but no matter what I do I wind up with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

My expected result is to be able to use GTK3 however no success to date.

Comment: Possible duplicate problem is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932407/which-python-should-i-install-and-how-when-using-msys2)

Comment: Namely, your major and minot versions of Python have to match the versions Gtk is compiled with.

Comment: If you figure out the solution, please post an answer or remove this question to keep this site cleaned up

Answer (score -2):

Basically I gave up on GTK and moved my project to wxPython.  It's a lot of work but so far the code works on Linux, Windows and Os X