# OpenRV build failing at building wheels for brotli, inflate64, pybcj, pycryptodomex, pyppmd, pyzstd

Tags: python, pypi, brotli

We're currently trying to build [Open RV](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenRV), but at the rvbootstrap stage, are getting errors having to do with failing to build wheels.

```
Failed to build brotli inflate64 pybcj pycryptodomex pyppmd pyzstd
ERROR: Could not build wheels for brotli, inflate64, pybcj, pycryptodomex, pyppmd, pyzstd, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Is this an error with python version incompatibility or otherwise?
OpenRV is working with python3.11, and we're building in msys64 in the OpenRV directory.

Thanks in advance!

I'm currently looking at the wheels for all the libraries listed (like this: https://pypi.org/project/Brotli/), but still not exactly sure how to proceed. Installing them on their own returns the same 'failed building wheel' message in the msys64 terminal

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's an issue with python version incompatibility. [OpenRV](https://pypi.org/project/OpenRV/) supports Python 3.6 and [Brotli](https://pypi.org/project/Brotli/) supports Python 2.7, 3.3 - 3.5.

All other packages listed should work because they are compatible with your python 3.11 as can be seen on their respective PyPi pages.

Would you try downgrading your python version to a version that supports all packages?

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up re-running the install in the mingw terminal, which worked. I think it may be because mingw accesses the python listed in the path (currently pointing to 3.6), if I'm understanding this correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932407/which-python-should-i-install-and-how-when-using-msys2